# Screwed up pip, getting "ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Somehow I screwed up my install of pip. I can't install anything using pip or even just get the version. When I try getting the version I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2353, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found
```

I found a Stack Overflow post that said I should re-install pip using: **python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip** but when I do that I get:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip
```

And of course trying to reinstall python using: **brew install python** gets me:

```
==> Installing dependencies for python: readline, sqlite, gdbm, makedepend, openssl
==> Installing python dependency: readline
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-6.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/readline-6.3.8.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/raw/746fc543e56bc37a26ccf05d2946a45176b0894e/readline-6.3.8.diff
##O=#    #                                                                                                                                           
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "readline--patch"
Download failed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jacknagel/d886531fb6623b60b2af/raw/746fc543e56bc37a26ccf05d2946a45176b0894e/readline-6.3.8.diff
```

I found another Stack Overflow post that said to use the ***get-pip.py*** file but doing that
throws the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23484, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "/tmp/tmpH6zFs7/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH6zFs7/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH6zFs7/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH6zFs7/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH6zFs7/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpH6zFs7/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py", line 22, in <module>
    @six.add_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_metaclass'
```

So as you can see I am bit stuck. I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing but I can't figure our what it is. Does anyone know how I can get my pip back & working? At this point I might also be interested in nuking my Python 2.7 install & starting again from scratch if that is possible. Thanks in advance.

__Mikk

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python get-pip.py`

Comment: @hoefling I don't understand your comment. If you are suggesting that I run the get-pip.py file using the python that is located in /usr/local/bin that won't work as there is no python in my /usr/local/bin. I do have a python in /usr/bin however running the get-pip.py file with /usr/bin/python only throws the same ```AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_metaclass'``` error as above.